# Target class does not exist / Laravel - composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to create a Composer package, but whenever I try to use a class from it,

```
\KhlilTurki97\LaravelRequestLogger\LaravelRequestLogger::class
```

I get

> Target class [KhlilTurki97\LaravelRequestLogger\LaravelRequestLogger] does not exist.

Here's my code

LaravelRequestLogger.php

```
namespace KhlilTurki97\LaravelRequestLogger;

use Closure;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LaravelRequestLogger
{
...
}
```

Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "khlilturki97/laravel-request-logger",
    "require": {
        "symfony/http-foundation": "^5.2",
        "symfony/console": "^5.2",
        "php": ">=7.2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "KhlilTurki97\\LaravelRequestLogger": "src/"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Khlil Turki",
            "email": "khlilturki97@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

[here's my files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXSfv.png)

Thanks a lot

**Update 1**

Changed `LaravelRequestLogger.php` to `Logger.php`

```
<?php

namespace KhlilTurki97\LaravelRequestLogger;

use Closure;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Logger
{
...
}
```

[here's my files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt0Sf.png)

Comment: try `"KhlilTurki97\\LaravelRequestLogger": "src/"` to `"KhlilTurki97\\": "src/"` in composer.json

Comment: @KamleshPaul still doesn't work

Comment: i event tried to change the class name to `Logger.php` to avoid confusion, but still doesn't work

Comment: Have to run composer dump-autoload after any changes to composer.json It's easy to forget

Comment: i've run it, still getting the same error

Comment: Pls update the code for the composer.json which you are using with changes after posting above (if any) and the directory structure for your package

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the composer.json autoload > psr4 as below and then run composer dump-atuoload

```json
{
    "name": "khlilturki97/laravel-request-logger",
    "require": {
        "symfony/http-foundation": "^5.2",
        "symfony/console": "^5.2",
        "php": ">=7.2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "KhlilTurki97\\LaravelRequestLogger\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Khlil Turki",
            "email": "khlilturki97@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it the same error `Target class [KhlilTurki97\LaravelRequestLogger\LaravelRequestLogger] does not exist.`? Are you getting this error in the package itself or after you require it in another project

Comment: am getting the error when i require it in an another project
> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [KhlilTurki97\LaravelRequestLogger\Logger] does not exist. in file 

`\KhlilTurki97\LaravelRequestLogger\Logger::class`

Comment: Remember after you make any changes to the package's namespace or composer.json you also need to run `composer update khlilturki97/laravel-request-logger` in the parent project. If your are requiring using path repository then it's okay however run composer dump-autoload in parent project.